# What functions with source and target the rational numbers satisfy the intermediate value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, rational-numbers, rational-functions

I am curious to find if there is a characterization of the set $S$ of all functions $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ where for all intervals $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{Q}$, there exists $x \in [a,b]$ for every $y$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ such that $f(x) = y$.

We see $f(x) = x$  has $f \in S$ since for any $y \in [f(a),f(b)] \subset \mathbb{Q}$ we can choose $x = y$ to have $f(x) = y$.

For a non example, take $f(x) = x^2$ and $[f(0),f(2)] = [0,4]$. We have $2 \in [0,4]$, but $f(x) = 2$ has no solutions. Similarly, $f(x) = x^n \not \in S$  for $n > 1$.

From the lemmas I've found so far, I conjecture $S$ is made up of piecewise defined functions of the form $a(x-b)^n+c$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $n \in \{-1,0,1\}$ with appropreate care taken to deal with discontinuities.

Here are my questions

- Do we miss anything restricting to piecewise rational functions $p(x)/q(x)$?
- Supposing $f(x), g(x) \not \in S$, can we show $f(x) + g(x) \not \in S$
- Is this well known appearing in a book somewhere?
- Is the corresponding question for number fields well known?

Comment: The Conway Base 13 function (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/a-definition-of-conway-base-13-function) looks as though it takes rationals to rationals and is surjective on rationals: I can find a rational number in any interval which maps to any given rational. In both base $10$ and base $13$ rationals are characterised as having a terminating 'decimal' expansion or an expansion which ultimately repeats, and both are handled by this construction.

Comment: My suspicion is that one can recursively define an immense variety of functions with this property that have nothing to do with polynomials, rational functions, or indeed even continuous functions. See [this paper of mine](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/UECFE.pdf) for some recursive constructions of order-preserving bijections of countable sets of real numbers; I believe the construction can be modified to product examples that satisfy the intermediate value property.