# How does one find the expected value of the Conway base-13 function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, when restricted to $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$?

Tags: measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure, expected-value, means

**Main Question:**

Using the Lebesgue measure, what is the expected value of the [Conway base-13 function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1156/1176963) $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, when restricted to $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$?

**Attempt:**

I’m not sure what the answer is; infact, I’m not sure an answer exists.

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1156/1176963), the Conway base-13 function is not computable (see [Noah Schweber’s comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709180/does-there-exist-an-explicit-and-bijective-function-that-satisfies-the-main-ques?noredirect=1#comment9971862_4709180) for a definition on *computability*).

Moreover, I find the function difficult to understand. (I only have knowledge up to Intro to Advanced Mathematics).

Due to my voracious interest in math, I’m unable to withhold questions until I’ve gained more knowledge. Does the **main question** have a positive answer?

**Edit:** Turns out the Conway base-13 function cannot have a range of $[0,1]$ and doesn’t satisfy the main question of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4709180/1176963). I will leave the question as it is.

Comment: This function does not look measurable. Hence, its expected value should be undefined.

Comment: @Kovomaka Then Noah Schweber and I were wrong about the function satisfying the main question of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4709180/1176963)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In what way do you plan on restricting $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ to $[0,1] \to [0,1]$? For any $r \in \mathbb R$, there exists a $c \in [0,1]$ where $f(c)=r$. So the only way of turning $f$ into a function $[0,1] \to [0,1]$ would be to compose it with some map that shrinks the image from $\mathbb R$ to $[0,1]$ -- Say something like $x \mapsto x - \lfloor x \rfloor$.

So, it is nonsensical to ask about any property of "the" restriction of $f$ into $[0,1] \to [0,1]$, since no natural and canoncial choice exists to transform one into the other. Perhaps you meant $[0,1] \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: Can you check if the Conway base-13 function satisfies the main question of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4709180/1176963). If not, the Noah Schwebers comments were incorrect.

Comment: It obviously doesn't - $f$ surjects onto $\mathbb R$ on any interval $(a,b) \subset \mathbb R$

Comment: Does the main question to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4709180/1176963) have a function that satisfies all the listed criteria?

Comment: I only intend to answer this question, not any new ones you've linked in the comments.